# Visited links lose CSS color animation in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation, hyperlink, visited

I'm trying to set color animations on links. Once a link has been visited in Chrome, the color animation is no longer applied. This is not the case for other animated styles (I've tested background color, font weight, and font size) nor in other browsers (Firefox, Safari, IE11).

Here's a demo:

http://codepen.io/benjarwar/pen/rVJbeR
http://s.codepen.io/benjarwar/debug/rVJbeR

HTML:

```
<a href='#' target='_blank' class='color'>Color Animation</a>
```

CSS:

```
a.color,
a.color:visited {
  -moz-animation: color-animation 1s ease-in-out infinite;
  -webkit-animation: color-animation 1s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: color-animation 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes color-animation {
  0% { color: #f00; }
  50% { color: #fc0; }
  100% { color: #f00; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes color-animation {
  0% { color: #f00; }
  50% { color: #fc0; }
  100% { color: #f00; }
}

@keyframes color-animation {
  0% { color: #f00; }
  50% { color: #fc0; }
  100% { color: #f00; }
}
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Visit the link above
2. Note the links have different animations
3. Click one of the links (all point to href="#")
4. Note that the color animation link is no longer animating
5. Remove the link from your browser history and refresh
6. Note that the animation returns once the link is removed from the history

Using Chrome Version 43.0.2357.130 on Mac OS 10.9.5

Comment: I made an issue on Chromium, but would love a work around in the meantime. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=506898

Comment: I have this problem too, and I'm guessing that it has to do with the CSS exploit, restricting the possibility to modify visited links except for very basic properties (such as color, etc.). I'm not sure, but having read other questions on here, it seems to be the only explanation that makes sense. If not, can someone please clarify?

Comment: Are you using any css resets like normalize.css?

Comment: Nope. This actually got marked as a bug by the Chromium team; fix is on the way.

Comment: You're not going to see the issue anymore with the above markup/CSS, because the Chromium team addressed the bug. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=506898

Comment: If this bug is resolved. Can it be closed please.

Comment: This [issue was fixed](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=506898) already. We should close this question.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is related to some general security/privacy issue in the past:

> We’re limiting the CSS properties that can be used to style visited
>   links to color, background-color, border-*-color, and outline-color
>   and the color parts of the fill and stroke properties.

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/
https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2010/03/31/plugging-the-css-history-leak/

Answer (score 1):

You could have used animation earlier but now most browsers restrict use of css style in visited. Only properties allow are

1. color
2. background-color
3. border-*-color
4. outline-color and the
5. color parts of the fill and stroke properties.

[source](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/)

**WHY**

Earlier people used to use visited hack to find out what websites you visited.

http://dbaron.org/mozilla/visited-privacy