# image slider working left to right , but not right to left

Tags: html, css, web, frontend

I've built an image slider using only HTML and CSS without using Javascript. It uses a hash based image selection and the `:target` CSS selector to access the hash name.

The problem is, that the sliding is working from left to right, but not right to left.

Changing the line to `transform: translateX(-100%);` to `transform: translateX(+100%);` should change the slide from right to left, but it is acting weird.

Here's the code:

```css
.slides {
    height: 70vh;
    width: 30vh;
    margin: auto;
    border: 2px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.slides li {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;

    z-index: 1;
}

.slides li img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.thumbnails {
    display: flex;
    width: 30vh;
    margin: auto;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;

}

.thumbnails li {
    flex: auto;
}



.thumbnails li img {
    width: 100%;

}

.slides li:target {
    z-index: 3;
    animation: slide 1s 1;
}

.slides li:not(:target) {
    animation: hidden 1s 1;
}

@keyframes slide {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}

@keyframes hidden {
    0% {
        z-index: 2;
    }

    100% {
        z-index: 2;
    }
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li id="slide1"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li id="slide2"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li id="slide3"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw3.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li id="slide4"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw4.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li id="slide5"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw5.jpg" alt="" /></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="thumbnails">
            <li>
                <a href="#slide1"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw1.jpg" /></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#slide2"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw2.jpg" /></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#slide3"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw3.jpg" /></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#slide4"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw4.jpg" /></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#slide5"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw5.jpg" /></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Interesting approach, didn't know the `:target` css selector up to now. What I found out is the following. It must be some kind of a timing issue, because if you change the animation count to 2, it's getting better: try animation: slide 1s 2;

Comment: another interesting observation: by first clicking on the images, then not clicking them but using the keyboard and navigation in the browser history, so like cmd+left and cmd+right on mac, the animation seems to work. but not via clicking. very strange

Comment: I've found something - maybe it has something to do with the restrictions because of the "visited" hack, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31212569/visited-links-lose-css-color-animation-in-chrome

Comment: Okay, my last thought. If I'm using any other property it works fine, so that could be just the issue, how the rendering engine/layouting works. If your content is in the DOM and it's getting a minus transformation, the bounding box still remains and the content is getting transformed. If it is a plus transformation, the layouting could reposition the content to be displayed at 0, which would look for us as if it weren't moved.

Comment: @Janos Vinceller , thanks for giving suggestions

Comment: @JanosVinceller , it's workinng now . I just commented  `overflow:hidden`  from  _slides_ class . I think you are right about layout thing ie  this is how layouting works , since even if we don't do `overflow:hidden`  , left to right sliding happens without issue.

Comment: cool, an easy solution at the end - I'll edit your question for the code to be accessible later, because now you changed the question's codebase

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to post a solution here with optimizations both visually and CSS-wise including the fix for the problem.

The solution is built on the idea of the original inquirer: removing the `overflow: hidden`.

I put another clipping layer above the original container (class `.clipper`) to have a smooth and visually attractive sliding experience.

I could eliminate multiple `width` and `height` lines.

I got rid of unnecessary spacings.

```css
.clipper {
    width: 30vh;
    overflow: clip;
}
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.slides {
    height: 50vh;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}

.slides li {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;

    z-index: 1;
}

.slides li img {
    height: 100%;
}

.thumbnails {
    left:0;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}

.thumbnails li {
    flex: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

.thumbnails li img {
    width: 100%;
}

.slides li:target {
    z-index: 3;
    animation: slide 1s 1;
}

.slides li:not(:target) {
    animation: hidden 1s 1;
}

@keyframes slide {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(+100%);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}

@keyframes hidden {
    0% {
        z-index: 2;
    }

    100% {
        z-index: 2;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="clipper">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li id="slide1"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li id="slide2"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li id="slide3"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw3.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li id="slide4"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw4.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li id="slide5"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw5.jpg" alt="" /></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="thumbnails">
            <li>
                <a href="#slide1"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw1.jpg" /></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#slide2"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw2.jpg" /></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#slide3"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw3.jpg" /></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#slide4"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw4.jpg" /></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#slide5"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw5.jpg" /></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You removed animation named _hidden_  , but it is needed . 
if we remove it -> when we click on one of _thumb_ images , if u notice , first image gets changed(everytime to same image , it is due to z-index) , then sliding starts

Comment: okay, that way I put it in again

Comment: yeah, you're right, now the problem is gone